# Show the equality holds for any $x \in [0, \pi]$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

We are considering a $2\pi$ periodic function defined on $x\in(-\pi,\pi)$ by 
$$f(x) =   \pi - x, 0<x<\pi  $$ and 0 otherwise.

I already computed the full Fourier series is equal to:
$$f(x) = {\pi\over4}+ \sum_{p=0}^\infty {2\over{\pi(2p+1)^2}}\cos[(2p+1)x] + \sum_{n=1}^\infty {1\over n}\sin(nx) $$

The next piece is to show that for any $ x\epsilon[0, \pi]$ the following equality holds:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {1\over n}\sin(nx)= {\pi\over4}+ \sum_{p=0}^\infty {2\over{\pi(2p+1)^2}}\cos[(2p+1)x]$$

I emailed my professor and he told me to deduce this from a result of the series pointwise convergence (limit).  The pointwise limit is:

$$\begin{cases}
\pi-x,  & \text{if $x \in (0,\pi)$} \\
0, & \text{if $x\in(-\pi,0)$}  \\
{\pi\over2}, & \text{if $x=0$} \\
\end{cases}$$

So how do I show the equality holds?

Comment: Hint: Look at the parity.

Comment: @DanielFischer are you talking about the parity of the cosine term, and the fact that every term will be negative?

Comment: I'm talking about the parity of the terms on both sides of the equation.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ok thanks, I'll try to play with that idea but nothing readily comes to mind.

Comment: Ping me if it doesn't work out after a while.

Comment: @DanielFischer Nothing - I know that at ${\pi \over 2}$ the cosine term vanishes and the sine term becomes an alternating series, but I don't see this helping me come to a conclusion..

Comment: @DanielFischer I think part of my problem may also be that I don't understand how parity can help as the parity of n is the only thing that could have impact on the Fourier series yet we need to prove for all x...

Comment: Ah, the parity of $n$ has nothing to do with it. The parity of the functions.

Comment: @DanFischer f(x) is an odd function. Cosine is even and sine is odd, is that what you're talking about? I don't see how that helps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $0 < x \leqslant \pi$. By the known pointwise convergence of the Fourier series, we have

$$0 = f(-x) = \frac{\pi}{4} + \sum_{p=0}^\infty \frac{2}{\pi(2p+1)^2}\cos \left[(2p+1)(-x)\right] + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin \left(n(-x)\right)}{n}.$$

Since $\cos$ is an even function and $\sin$ odd, this becomes

$$0 = \frac{\pi}{4} + \sum_{p=0}^\infty \frac{2}{\pi(2p+1)^2}\cos \left[(2p+1)x\right] - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin (nx)}{n},$$

and that is evidently equivalent to

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin (nx)}{n} = \frac{\pi}{4} + \sum_{p=0}^\infty \frac{2}{\pi(2p+1)^2}\cos \left[(2p+1)x\right].\tag{1}$$

Note that $(1)$ does *not* hold for $x = 0$, only for $0 < x \leqslant \pi$ (by peridicity, for $2k \pi < x \leqslant (2k+1)\pi$).

Comment: That was much more simple then I assumed. So since we know the point wise convergence exists we can use the fact that it converges point wise iff f(x)=-f(-x) ...

Comment: No, we don't have $f(x) = -f(-x)$, $f$ is not odd. But since the odd and the even part of $f$ cancel on $[-\pi,0)$, they must coincide on $(0,\pi]$.